# Implications of the order function

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $m$ be a positive integer and let $a \in \mathbb{Z}$.

> Prove that if $\operatorname{ord}_ma=xy$ (with x and y positive integers), then $\operatorname{ord}_m(a^x)=y$.

I know that $\operatorname{ord}_ma=xy$ implies that $a^{xy}=1\mod m$ which then implies that $(a^{x})^{y}=1\mod m$  But is that enough because how do I know that $y$ is the lowest such value that will give $1 \mod m$.  How do I know that $y$ will be the lowest value that will yield $1 \mod m$.

> Prove that if $\operatorname{ord}_ma=m-1$, then $m$ is prime.

I know that if $m$ is prime, then $a^{\phi(m)}=1 \mod m$ and $\phi(m)=m-1$.  Is that all I need to show that if $\operatorname{ord}_ma=m-1$ or is there more to it?

Answer (score 0):

I.e. if $xy$ is the least positive integer $k$ such that $a^k\equiv 1\pmod{m}$, then prove two things:

$1)\ $ $\left(a^x\right)^y\equiv 1\pmod{m}$.

$2)\ $ There doesn't exist $1\le t<y$ such that $\left(a^x\right)^t\equiv 1\pmod{m}$.

$(1)$ follows from $a^{xy}\equiv 1\pmod{m}$. Prove $(2)$ by contradiction: if such a $t$ exists, then $a^{xt}\equiv 1\pmod{m}$, but $1\le xt<xy=\text{ord}_m(a)$, contradiction.

---

Since $\text{ord}_m(a)$ exists, we know $\gcd(a,m)=1$. Since $\text{ord}_m(a)=m-1$, powers of $a$ go through $1,2,\ldots, m-1$ mod $m$, so $1,2,\ldots,m-1$ are coprime to $m$, so $m$ is prime.